# How to parse nested elements in XML

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have this use case where I need to extract some data from XML doc and then take some actions using simple if/else statements.

I have had partial success using ElementTree library where I can retrieve "node id" "name" & "address" using get and find (). But trying to get 'connected enabled' from XML body is not working.

Basically, I need to know if 'connected enabled' is true or false and take appropriate action. I went through the documentation, tried various methods but no luck!

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

response = requests.get('http://10.xx.xx.xx/restapi/nodes')
#print(response.text)
tree = ET.fromstring(response.text)
for node in tree.findall('node'):
    nodeid = node.get('id')
    name = node.find('name').text
    address = node.find('address').text
    status = node.find('connected enabled')
    print(nodeid, name, address, status)
```

I expect to see if connected enabled = false or true, but all I get is "NONE"

This is the output I get:

```
0B7E2B74-DA55-4AD3-BDEF-11EAC08A2622 i-xxx 10.33.xx.xx:45000 None
32A1A15C-4DB9-4634-B267-2F2760C3EAD3 i-yyy 10.33.xx.xx:45000 None
```

This is the XML data:

```
<node id='0B7E2B74-DA55-4AD3-BDEF-11EAC08A2622'>
<address>10.33.1.240:45000</address>
<name>i-0f60ca5b3447061e3</name>
<partition>Default</partition>
<version></version>
<active enabled='true' />
<connected enabled='false' />
<licensed enabled='true' />
<capacity>36</capacity>
<cpu_cores>36</cpu_cores>
<health>
<cpu_usage>0.00163664</cpu_usage>
<memory_usage>4</memory_usage>
<disk_usage>73</disk_usage>
<network_usage>3672</network_usage>
</health>
</node>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
status = node.find('connected').get('enabled')
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you.